# search user id in database and display user name in second form c#

Tags: c#

I have a table with the columns Name, UserID, Password, UserType. 
Also I have a login form where the user types userID/password combination, selects userstype (student or instructor) and clicks the button OK. If such combination of id/password exists the program opens a new form - student or instructor form depending on selected user type. What I want to do is, when the second form opens the label on the form to indicate: Logged in: "Name". I know that if I put the code in the form1

```
if(rbtnStud.checked)
{
   Students form = new Students (txtUID.Text); 
   formShowDialog; 
   this.Hide();
}
```

and in the second form

```
public Students(string txtBox) 
 { 
     InitializeComponent();  
     lblName.Text = txtBox; 
 }
```

this will display UserID in the label. But I want Name from the table to be displayed, not UserID. Is it possible?

Thank you.

OK, here is the additional information: I am using WinForms 
Code to pull out information from database in "LoginDB" class:

```
            SqlConnection conn = SchoolDB.Connected();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserType from Login where UserID=@id and Password=@pwd", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", UserID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Password);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
```

and on main form:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable result = LoginDB.Login(txtUID.Text, txtpwd.Text);
            if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                if (rbtnStud.Checked)
                {
                    Students form = new Students(txtUID.Text);
                    form.ShowDialog();
                    this.Hide();
                } 
             else if{}
```

Comment: you must be looking up the user from the database to confirm their credentials, so why not just grab the name at that point?

Comment: Anything is possible as long as you're willing to code it.  Unfortunately you haven't given us enough of your code to give you more guidance.  How are you pulling data from your table?  How are you connecting to the database?  Are you using WinForms or ASP.net or MVC?

Comment: Since UserId is your primary key, you can just make a query to the table and query for the Name of that UserId. Do that operation in Load() method of Form 2.

Comment: Thank you for comments, but I don't know where to put the code that will transform userid into name and display in label. I am willing to code anything as long as I know how. I am still a rookie in c#

Comment: Found it. Thank you very much for idea @OsmanEsen. Works now. Now I can go to next step. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the SqlCommand to return the Name instead of the UserType:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name from Login where UserID=@id and Password=@pwd", conn);
```

Update the click event on the main form:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable result = LoginDB.Login(txtUID.Text, txtpwd.Text);
            if (result.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                if (rbtnStud.Checked)
                {
                    // pass the name to the students form
                    Students form = new Students(dt.Rows[0]["Name"] as string);
                    form.ShowDialog();
                    this.Hide();
                } 
             else if{}
....
```